# IBDesignable with CollectionView crashes when add value to DataSource

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I am working on a small `UIView` component that displays hashtags in a `UICollectionView` and for some reasons I needed to make it "editable" through the Interface Builder... Therefore, I made it `IBDesignable`.

Everything works except when in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` I am trying to append a object to the `datasource`, so the list displays something when integrated somewhere in the storyboard.

Arriving to the line `self.hashtags.append(hashtag)`, this crashes. If I remove this line, the view is rendered properly on the storyboard, if I put it again ---> crash... After all my debugging it seems that IB can't access this property or sees it nil.

I can't debug **anything**, Xcode doesn't let me debug the selected views in Storyboard > Editor (being on macOS Mojave causes bugs). My view doesn't have a `.xib`, and has both required `init`'s

I also checked the logs in the Console.app and theres nothing. Here is the main error message given by the Storyboard :

*Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for PublishViewController (tSg-9E-Vz3): The agent threw an exception.*

Code (what matters)

```
@IBDesignable
class HashtagView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return view
    }()

    open var hashtags: [HashTag] = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()

        self.hashtags.append(HashTag(word: "it works")) < CRASH
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Setup function()

```
func setup() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.Custom.ligthGray
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius

    let alignedFlowLayout = AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout(horizontalAlignment: .left, verticalAlignment: .top)
    alignedFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
    alignedFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 7.0
    alignedFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = alignedFlowLayout
    self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

    self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "RemovableTagCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "RemovableTagCollectionViewCell")

    self.addSubview(self.collectionView)

    self.collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: where is the setup function?

Comment: @agibson007 just added it. Im sure it's not from here it goes through it without any problem

Comment: Not really sure if collectionView can be IBDesignable. Maybe a UIStackview instead

Comment: @agibson007 well, I wasn't sure either... Then I saw someone doing it...
But again, the UICollectionView doesn't seem to be the problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the setup was definitely relevant. Apparently IB was crashing trying to load your cell for your UICollectionView.  It could not load the Nib file. It did not have anything to do with the append it just crashed at the same time.  I replicated your issue then created a cell with code and it all worked fine.  Let me know if this helps and answers your question.  All the required code is there.

```
import UIKit

struct HashTag {
    var word:String?
}

class HashCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var wordLabel : UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        lbl.textColor = .black
        return lbl
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(wordLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addSubview(wordLabel)
    }

    func configureWithTag(tag:HashTag) {
        wordLabel.text = tag.word
    }

}

@IBDesignable
class HashTagView: UIView {

    private var sizingLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
   lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        return view
    }()

    var hashtags: [HashTag] = [HashTag(word: "this works")]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }


    func setup(){
        sizingLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)

        self.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = self.bounds
        collectionView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        collectionView.register(HashCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "hashCell")
        self.addSubview(collectionView)

        for x in 0..<10{
            addHashTag(tag: "This is more \(x)")
        }

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func addHashTag(tag:String){
        let newHash = HashTag(word: tag)
        self.hashtags.append(newHash)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = self.bounds
    }

}

extension HashTagView: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hashtags.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hashCell", for: indexPath) as? HashCollectionViewCell{
            let tag = self.hashtags[indexPath.item]
            cell.configureWithTag(tag: tag)
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let tag = self.hashtags[indexPath.item]
        sizingLabel.text = tag.word
        sizingLabel.sizeToFit()
        return sizingLabel.frame.size
    }
}
```

**Result:**[image]

**2) You can load a nib into the programmatically created cell and it will work.**  An example would look like this instead for the part that is the programatic cell.

**Cell Code with View extension using nib inside cell:**

```
extension UIView {
    func loadNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nibName = type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    }
}

class HashCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var hashTagNib : HashTagNibView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        if let htn = HashTagNibView().loadNib() as? HashTagNibView{
            hashTagNib = htn
            hashTagNib?.frame = self.bounds
            hashTagNib?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
           self.addSubview(htn)
        }

    }

    func configureWithTag(tag:HashTag) {
        if let htn = hashTagNib{
            htn.hashTagButtonLabel.setTitle(tag.word, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

**Nib setup would looks like this:**
[image: nib]

This might give you more flexibility depending on what you are doing and the result is similar except in the nib example I used a UIButton.
[image]

Comment: I will give it a try when I’m home. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the cause. This is weird. May I know I you debugged all this and figured that out ?

Comment: Well I clicked in editor at the top and clicked debug selected view. I saw the stack trace briefly before Xcode completely crashed. It would never come up again. But I commented everything out except the append and no crash. It was only after the colllectionview started loading that it crashed (empty array no loading and no crash) so I quickly but together a programmatic cell and it worked perfectly. Been doing this a while so really never have been stumped on a issue I want to solve. Learned how to isolate problems. If this is acceptable answer please accept.

Comment: @FrenchFalcon I did add a way for you to use a nib view inside the cell and it should work.  Curious that collection view could not load the nib directly as a cell.  I think because when IBDesignable is used it only calls init with frame.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks. My Xcode is totally full of bugs, and the crash is the only thing it reports. Then it’s a long series of rebuilds, cleans, and even delete DerivedData. On my side, debugging selected views gives me a “can’t attach PID error” mainly because of Xcode beta and macOS beta, so I had no chance to see this error coming. Do you know why it is impossible to load directly the cell as nib but loading its content as an actual nib works ?

Comment: Oh sorry I couldn’t see the end of your previous comment. I get it for the cell and nib. That sucks though. I’m not a fan of IBDesignables and IB in general. Makes it too time consuming and hard to make simple stuff working. Thanks for your help.